# Script for running Feature Class To Coverage tool runs into error on arcgis server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I have created a script for converting feature classes to coverage and it runs fine in arcmap. But after publishing and running it on the server, it fails to execute and returns the following error message:

"Unable to complete operation.
Error executing tool.: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 154, in execute File "c:\program files\arcgis\server\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1576, in FeatureclassToCoverage raise e RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool Failed to execute (CoverageArcsNodes). Failed to execute (Select Coverage Features)."

```
import arcpy
import tempfile

class Toolbox(object):
def __init__(self):     
    self.label = "Toolbox"
    self.alias = ""

    self.tools = [CoverageArcsNodes]


class CoverageArcsNodes(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.label = "Select Coverage Features"
    self.description = ""
    self.canRunInBackground = True

def getParameterInfo(self):
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Input Line Feature Classes",
    name="in_lineFeatures",
    datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input",
        multiValue=True
    )   

    # Second parameter
    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Input Point Feature Classes",
    name="in_pointFeatures",
    datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input",
    multiValue=True
    )

    params = [param0, param1]

    return params

def execute(self, params, messages):

    arcpy.env.workspace="C:\\Users\\DeveloperA\\Desktop\\SEMNAN DB\\SemnanDB.SDE.gdb"
    coverageOutDir= "C:\\Users\\DeveloperA\\Desktop\\tempCoverage"
    #lines
    #lineValues= params[0].valueAsText.split(";")
    lineValues= params[0].values
    layerCnt=1      

    for fc in lineValues:                           
        layerName="layer"+str(layerCnt)
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc,"featureClassName","TEXT") 
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,layerName)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layerName)
        arcpy.AddMessage("workspace="+arcpy.env.workspace)                              
        layerCnt=layerCnt+1

    #points         
    pointValues= params[1].values       

    for fc in pointValues:                                      
        layerName="layer"+str(layerCnt)
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc,"featureClassName","TEXT") 
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,layerName)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layerName)          
        layerCnt=layerCnt+1 


    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(arcpy.env.workspace, "points", "POINT",params[1].values[0])
    arcpy.AddField_management("points","featureClassName","TEXT")       
    arcpy.AddField_management("points","OriginalOBJECTID","TEXT")

    linesObjIdFldMap = arcpy.FieldMap()
    linesObjIdFldMap.addInputField(params[0].values[0],"OBJECTID")
    linesObjIdFldMap.outputField.name="OriginalOBJECTID"        
    linesFeatureClassFldMap = arcpy.FieldMap()
    linesFeatureClassFldMap.addInputField(params[0].values[0],"featureClassName")
    linesFeatureClassFldMap.outputField.name="featureClassName" 
    lineFieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
    lineFieldMappings.addFieldMap(linesObjIdFldMap)
    lineFieldMappings.addFieldMap(linesFeatureClassFldMap)

    pointsObjIdFldMap = arcpy.FieldMap()
    pointsObjIdFldMap.addInputField(params[1].values[0],"OBJECTID")
    pointsObjIdFldMap.outputField.name="OriginalOBJECTID"       
    pointsFeatureClassFldMap = arcpy.FieldMap()
    pointsFeatureClassFldMap.addInputField(params[1].values[0],"featureClassName")
    pointsFeatureClassFldMap.outputField.name="featureClassName"                                        

    pointFieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
    pointFieldMappings.addTable(params[1].values[0])
    pointFieldMappings.addFieldMap(pointsObjIdFldMap)
    pointFieldMappings.addFieldMap(pointsFeatureClassFldMap)    

    arcpy.Merge_management(params[0].values,"lines",lineFieldMappings)
    arcpy.Append_management(params[1].values,"points","NO_TEST",pointFieldMappings)             
    arcpy.FeatureclassToCoverage_conversion(in_features="'"+arcpy.env.workspace+"\\lines' ARC;'"+arcpy.env.workspace+"\\points' POINT;",out_cover=coverageOutDir)       

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(coverageOutDir+"\\arc","lines_layer")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lines_layer")      

    return
```

I am a total newbie this sort of stuff and I am totally confused how to proceed.

P.S my guess is that I have messed up the workspaces and paths (dunno how), either that **or arcgis server does not support the tool because when I comment out the line that calls the arcpy.FeatureclassToCoverage_conversion tool the script executes with no errors.**

Comment: I suggest publishing a script tool instead of Python toolbox as a GP service

Comment: You have a couple of indentation issues (maybe from pasting, but worth checking) `class Toolbox(object):` and `class CoverageArcsNodes(object):` should have the following `def` block indented further

Comment: @Midavalo Thanks for the comment. It's because of pasting of course. As I said, it runs fine in ArcMap.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Thanks for the comment. Do you mean a python tool? Not sure if that would make any difference. Worth a try though. :)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I didn't see an essential difference in two approaches. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/comparing-custom-and-python-toolboxes.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1CD3AC636D3246CBA1865CEF9B9201FB
Also I am going to edit my question.

Comment: Run the featureClassToCoverage in desktop and copy results as a python snippet. Use os.path.join() and str.format() to specify your tool input  and output paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this line
`arcpy.FeatureclassToCoverage_conversion(in_features="'"+arcpy.env.workspace+"\\lines' ARC;'"+arcpy.env.workspace+"\\points' POINT;",out_cover=coverageOutDir)`
to this

```
arcpy.FeatureclassToCoverage_conversion(in_features="'lines' ARC; 'points' POINT;",out_cover=coverageOutDir)
```

and it worked. :)